# Dynamically create big tables with react

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I am trying to write code in React in order to dynamically, i.e., without knowing the data in advance, render big tables (like 10.000 rows X 350 cols) starting from a csv file that is uploaded trough an input form.

I wrote the code that you can find below. It works with limited tables, e.g. 2000 rows x 350 cols. With the target table (10.000 x 350) Chrome stop the execution telling me 'Paused before potential out-of-memory crash' and, after that, the application crashes. Microsoft Edge is not able to run the application too. There is a way to improve my code in order to avoid that?

Thank you so much in advance!

```
    populateRows() {
        function populateCols(cols, lineNumber) {
            let result = [];
            for(let i=0; i<cols.length; i++) {
                if(lineNumber === 0){
                    result.push(<th key={lineNumber + '_' + i}>{cols[i]}</th>);
                }
                else {
                    result.push(<td key={lineNumber + '_' + i}>{cols[i]}</td>);
                }
            }
            return result;
        }

        function populateBody(lines) {
            const result = [];
            for(let line = 1; line < lines.length; line++){
                result.push(<tr key={'line_' + line}>{populateCols(lines[line].split(','), line)}</tr>);
            }
            return result;
        }

        let result = [];
        result.push(<thead key={"thead"}><tr key={'headRow'}>{populateCols(this.props.cols, 0)}</tr></thead>);

        result.push(<tbody key={"tbody"}>{populateBody(this.props.lines)}</tbody>);

        return result;
    }

    render() {

        return (
            <div>
                <p className={'noBoardersP'}><b> {this.props.caption} </b></p>
                <div className="tableDiv">
                    <table>
                        {this.populateRows()}
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
```

Comment: I think you'd be better off with a library to achieve this , if your table is very large probably one which implements a virtualized approach, e.g. https://github.com/bvaughn/react-virtualized. If you implement your own there is a lot of work to be done and kind of re inventing the wheel (IMHO)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**React virtualized** is made for this exact reason.

https://github.com/bvaughn/react-virtualized

And a working example

https://bvaughn.github.io/react-virtualized/#/components/List

Comment: Thank you Mark. I used react-virtualized as suggested but in the end I used Multigrid (from react-virtualized) instead of Table because I needed the possibility to have overflow on the x-axis.

Comment: Nice!  I had to implement this for a product at work utilizing react-pdf.js.  It took a while to get them to play nicely together, but it really helped with performance.  Did you hit any snags getting it to work?

Answer (score 1):

It is always better to use the library. Use the [React Table](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-table) library with pagination. With it you can render as many rows as possible but with max 100 rows visible at a time.